# Holomorphic $(p,0)$ form induces an isomorphism: $H^1(X,T_X)\to H^1(X,\Omega^{p-1})$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, deformation-theory

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold which admits a holomorphic $(p,0)$ form $\eta$ which is everywhere non-degenerate. If dim $H^0(X,\Omega^p)=1$, then is the contraction map
$$\lrcorner \eta:H^1(X,T_X)\to H^1(X,\Omega^{p-1})$$
an isomorphism?

From [Voisin](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.482.5539&rep=rep1&type=pdf) p.26 example 7, maybe we can conclude it is true for $p=2$? But for a general $p$, does it still holds?

Comment: What does "non-degenerate" mean for a differential form?

Comment: @AGlearner, thanks for remind me this negligence, maybe we can define non-degenerate as: we say a $(p,0)$ form $\eta$ is non-degenerate if and only if for $v_i\in T^{1,0}(X)$, $\eta(v_1,\cdots,v_p)\ne 0$ implies all $v_i\ne 0, i=1,\cdots,p$, is this definition ok?

Comment: No, every differential form (even the zero form) will satisfy that condition. You may want to study $p=2$ case carefully before generalizing to higher degrees. Here is a related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19066/non-degenerate-multilinear-forms